# What is the optimization formulation of this question?

Tags: optimization

I found the following puzzle on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388060/solving-puzzle-in-python):

> Puzzle:
>
> A merchant has a 40 kg weight which he used in his shop. Once, it fell
>   from his hands and was broken into 4 pieces. But surprisingly, now he
>   can weigh any weight between 1 kg to 40 kg with the combination of
>   these 4 pieces.
>
> So question is, what are weights of those 4 pieces?

I have recently begun reading about Optimizations so I got curious: Is there an optimization formulation for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more general problem is known as BACHET’S PROBLEM OF WEIGHTS.
See the paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5486) by Edwin O'Shea or look at page $149$ of An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by G.H. Hardy and E.M. Wright, $6$th edition. ${} {} {}$